# Behavior vs Event Handler

Tags: xamarin.forms

What's the purpose of having behaviors in Xamarin.Forms? Isn't it possible to add new functionality to UI elements through event handlers? I am confused about when to use an event handler and when to use behaviors.

Comment: There is some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017496/what-is-the-difference-between-behaviors-and-event-triggers), but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple answer and is only intended to start your research. Undoubtedly a better answer will come along. I am still working through this and will keep an eye on it because I too would like an answer that is more thorough than mine.

With proper separation of your View and ViewModel, Events aren't really the way to go. Behaviors allow you to maintain a proper MVVM approach (for example, when calling a `Command` from an `Entry`'s `Completed` event) by using an [`EventToCommandBehavior`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/reusable/event-to-command-behavior/) system.

Additionally, Behaviors allow you to create prepackaged, well, behaviors that can be applied to multiple controls' events without having to reuse code.